# Remember multiple passport authentications for the same user in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm attempting to make a nodejs app (without a database) that allows a user to login with Instagram, Twitter, or both, and then display info based on that.

Currently, I create a new TwitterStrategy and InstagramStrategy, seralise and deserialise the user, and can handle logins to either site.

This is how I deal with authentications:

```
app.get("/tw/login", passport.authenticate("twitter"));

app.get("/tw/cb", passport.authenticate("twitter", {
  failureRedirect: "/"
}),
  function(request, response) {
    response.redirect("/")
});

app.get("/ig/login", passport.authenticate("instagram"));

app.get("/ig/cb", passport.authenticate("instagram", {
  failureRedirect: "/"
}),
  function(request, response) {
    response.redirect("/")
});
```

However, if I login with Twitter I can access the response details from `/`, but only until I login with Instagram (at which point, I can only access the Instagram details by GETting the request to `/`.

How can I make it so I can remember both responses at `/`?

Also, it seems that logging in to one site overwrites the info for the other in the session, which is not desired.

Comment: I was thinking of redirecting the Twitter response to `/twitter` and the IG response to `/instagram`, then redirecting these pages to `/`, so I can use GET requests on `/` to obtain the responses when I want, but I want to know if I can avoid the double redirect scenario?

Comment: You need twitter and instagram to serialize/deserialize to the same profile.

Comment: well not *exactly* the same profile. just have a single user object that contains both instagram and twitter

Comment: @Catalyst something like this? `var Obj = {ig: //ig strat, twittter: //twitter strat`, then `passport.use(Obj)`, and then use `app.get("/instagram/login", passport.authenticate("Obj.ig"));` rather than `app.get("/instagram/login", passport.authenticate("instagram"));`?

Comment: I get an `Error: Authentication strategies must have a name` error when I try this

Comment: fixing this (with `passport.use("obj", Obj)`) now provides a `TypeError: strategy.authenticate is not a function` error

Comment: I don't think you really needed to change your passport usage all that much. just the part where you save to the database, and how your database schema is setup.